# Internet Sharing in a LAN using VPN

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, internet

I have a Lan with 6 pcs, one of them I used as a server with windows 2003 server.
I want to share Internet between PCs on Lan , using VPN , and just how has valid user on server can access to Internet.
I setup VPN on server, the problem is steel some PCs without using VPN have Internet and I can't control them , I use DHCP and all pcs have IP forom 10.0.0.11 to 10.0.0.100 ( server IP is : 10.0.0.10)and I setup VPN to set IP from 10.0.0.101 to 10.0.0.121

other PCs can access to ftp , pop3 ... without using VPN and just browsing web pages need to connect VPN.

What is wrong? how can I manage my Internet usage?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a proxy or gateway solution not necessarily a VPN.

If you want to enforce a policy using the 2003 server for Internet traffic you will need to either block all other hosts from the Internet by using your router's configuration tools or setup the 2003 server as a router and connect only it to the Internet.  The first method is usually easier to implement but can cause some user confusion.

Depending on your needs you may want to also setup [automatic proxy configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config).

I know this answer is somewhat general. I hope I covered it with enough information to get you pointed in the right direction.

Normally VPNs are used to connect hosts and networks privately across public networks.  Proxies are used to enforce network policies on traffic crossing a network boundary.  Gateways (routers) are used to actually pass traffic across boundaries.